# Problem while using user insert for getter

Tags: java

This code here is doing next:

The user displays a list of flights, each with its own ID, and chooses to enter the ID. I print that flight by checking which ID was chosen by the user.

```
public void chooseFlight(ArrayList<Flight> flightList) {
    System.out.println("Choose one flight by ID: ");
    int userChoiceFlight = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();

    for (Flight tempUserChoiceFlight : flightList) {
        if (userChoiceFlight == tempUserChoiceFlight.getId()) {
            System.out.println("You flight from: " + tempUserChoiceFlight.getFrom()
                    + " to: " + tempUserChoiceFlight.getTo());


        }
    }
}
```

As you can see this is the main part:

```
  for (Flight tempUserChoiceFlight : flightList) {
        if (userChoiceFlight == tempUserChoiceFlight.getId()) {
```

Now Im creating new metho called `promoCode`, what is going on in it:

I ask the user if he has a promo code, if there is I check that code with the ID flight he chose, each flight has its own promo code.

What is my problem, in that method I can't access the flight chosen by the user. This is the method:

```
@Override
public void promoCode(ArrayList<Flight> flightList) {
    System.out.println("Do you have promo code? (yes / no) ");
    String yesNo = scanner.nextLine();

    if (yesNo.contains("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Enter promo code");
        String userPromoCode = scanner.nextLine();
        for (Flight tempUserChoiceFlight : flightList) {
            if (userPromoCode.contains(tempUserChoiceFlight.getPromoCode())) {
                System.out.println("Cool you have discount!");
                break;
            } else if (yesNo.contains("no")) {
                System.out.println("Find one, you have no discount!");
                break;
            } else if (!userPromoCode.contains(tempUserChoiceFlight.getPromoCode())) {
                System.out.println("Promo code is not valid!");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong input!");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And this is method all in one, where I take user flight and check promo code, here works fine, I want to separate user selection flight and checking promo code in two methods.

This method works:

```
public void chooseFlight(ArrayList<Flight> flightList) {
    System.out.println("Choose one flight by ID: ");
    int userChoiceFlight = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();

    for (Flight tempUserChoiceFlight : flightList) {
        if (userChoiceFlight == tempUserChoiceFlight.getId()) {
            System.out.println("You flight from: " + tempUserChoiceFlight.getFrom()
                    + " to: " + tempUserChoiceFlight.getTo());

            System.out.println("Do you have promo code? (yes / no) ");
            String yesNo = scanner.nextLine();

            if (yesNo.contains("yes")) {
                System.out.println("Enter promo code");
                String userPromoCode = scanner.nextLine();

                if (userPromoCode.contains(tempUserChoiceFlight.getPromoCode())) {
                    System.out.println("Cool you have discount!");
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Promo code is not valid!");
                    break;
                }

            } else if (yesNo.contains("no")) {
                System.out.println("Find one, you have no discount!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong input!");
            }
        }
```

and I'm checking the promo code here:

```
 if (userPromoCode.contains(tempUserChoiceFlight.getPromoCode())) {
```

Once again, in the new method, I cannot get the flight ID selected by the user to compare the promo code from the selected flight and the promo code of the user entering.

Comment: This is obviously a learning assignment.  Do you have to use the function signatures as is?  Because I would expect chooseFlight to return the flight chosen, which could be passed in as a parameter to future functions.  In that case, promoCode would take a single flight (the one the user chose) as a parameter.

Comment: Also, don't use `.contains()` to check if two Strings are equal. Use `.equals()`.

Comment: This is not a learning assignment, I give to myself small project, but Im stuck here. How I can do that? Changing `void` to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the name of your class is **FlightSelector** and both "**chooseFlight**" and "**promoCode**" methods are in this class, use the following code:

```
    public class FlightSelector {

    private Flight selectedFlight;
    
    public void chooseFlight(ArrayList<Flight> flightList) {
        System.out.println("Choose one flight by ID: ");
        int userChoiceFlight = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
    
        for (Flight tempUserChoiceFlight : flightList) {
            if (userChoiceFlight == tempUserChoiceFlight.getId()) {
                System.out.println("You flight from: " + tempUserChoiceFlight.getFrom()
                        + " to: " + tempUserChoiceFlight.getTo());

                 selectedFlight = temUserChoiceFlight;
                 promoCode(flightList);
                 break;
    
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void promoCode(ArrayList<Flight> flightList) {
        System.out.println("Do you have promo code? (yes / no) ");
        String yesNo = scanner.nextLine();
    
        if (yesNo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                System.out.println("Enter promo code");
                String userPromoCode = scanner.nextLine();
                if (userPromoCode.equalsIgnoreCase(selectedFlight.getPromoCode())) {
                    System.out.println("Cool you have discount!");

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Promo code is not valid!");
                } 
    
       } else {
           System.out.println("Find one, you have no discount!");
       }
    }
}
```

I also assume that you can't change the signature of **promoCode** method, so I don't pass the **selectedFlight** as a parameter. Otherwise, I suggest to change the signature to:

```
public void promoCode(Flight selectedFlight)
```

In this case, you don't need:

```
private Flight selectedFlight;
```

Comment: This works, thank you. Just one small problem, after I type correct promo code and program print me `System.out.println("Cool you have discount!");`, program again ask me for promo code

Comment: @asu This could only happen if flightList contains 2 Flight objects with the same id. But if you add "break" statement, it should solve the issue. I will update my answer.